# UWP app crashing instead of showing message dialogue box

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a pivot control in my uwp app. In pivot_selectionchanged event i have written to show message dialogue.

After generating the package of uwp app when I have clicked on pivot item some alert message dialogues should display but it is not displaying instead at that point app is crashing.
This is with some machines only.
Can any one know the reason?

The code I have written is

```
private void OpenBillPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool Isreturn = false;
    bool IsExchange = false;

    Isreturn = checkUserPermission(Constants.Return);
    IsExchange = checkUserPermission(Constants.Exchange);
    if (Application.Current.Resources[Constants.RETURNS].ToString() == Constants.FALSE_CAMELCASE)
        Isreturn = false;
    else
        Isreturn = true;
    if (Application.Current.Resources[Constants.EXCHANGES].ToString() == Constants.FALSE_CAMELCASE)
        IsExchange = false;
    else
        Isreturn = true;

    if ((txtblStatus.Text == "Cancelled" || txtblStatus.Text=="Draft") && (OpenBillPivot.SelectedIndex == 1 || OpenBillPivot.SelectedIndex == 2 || OpenBillPivot.SelectedIndex == 3))
    {
        TransactionDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ReturnDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ExchangeDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //SimpleMessageDialog(ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("PLEASE_CLEAR_THE_BILL"), ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("ALERT"));
    }

    else if (OpenBillPivot.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        if ((txtblStatus.Text == "Pending" && txtblBillDue.Text != Constants.ZERO))
        {
            ReturnDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ExchangeDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            SimpleMessageDialog(ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("PLEASE_CLEAR_THE_BILL"), ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("ALERT"));
        }

        else
        {
            if (!Isreturn)
            {
                ReturnDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                SimpleMessageDialog("Access Denied", ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("ALERT"));
            }
            else
                ReturnDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
```

and message dialogue code:

```
private async void SimpleMessageDialog(string Message, string Title)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Message, Title);
    dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Maybe surround your code with try/catch statements so that you can find the exception that happens when it crashes ? The exception message might help you find out what's actually happenning.

Comment: you must post the exception of your application to get more details. Thank you!

Comment: Why do people suggest wrapping code in try/catch statement to find an exception? This is completely unnecessary, and a terrible idea! **When an exception is thrown, your debugger will break in and let you see it immediately at that point. You don't need a bunch of catch blocks that display message boxes.** The global, unhandled exception handler already does that! All that adding a bunch of try/catch blocks does is help to ensure that exceptions are silenced and you never get a good chance to debug them.

Answer (score 1):

it may be because you are actually not waiting for the message to show, change the return type from void to Task:

```
private async Task SimpleMessageDialog(string Message, string Title)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Message, Title);
    dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

and await it:

```
await SimpleMessageDialog(ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("PLEASE_CLEAR_THE_BILL"), ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("ALERT"));
```

you need to change the method to async as well:

```
private async void OpenBillPivot_SelectionChanged...
```

Comment: openbillpivot_selectionchanged is an event so we can't change that one.

Comment: it is an event handler and I don't see any reason you can't mark it async